# What is the Lie derivative of the Laplacian of a smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics

I am fiddling around with some computations in (semi-)Riemannian geometry and have come across the following term:

$$
\int_{M} \phi L_{X}(\Delta_{g}\phi)dvol_{g},
$$

where $\Delta_{g}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator and $L_{X}$ is the Lie derivative. Ideally, I would like this term to be $0$ or have it be a "surface" term, either in the way that the scalar part in front of the volume form is a covariant derivative or that the entire integrand is an exact form. Of course, if $\phi$ is harmonic, this whole thing is zero, which is good for other reasons, but I'm curious to see how this could be transfigured anyway.

Comment: My first intuition is to write $\Delta = d\circ \delta + \delta \circ d$ in terms of the codifferential and the differential, and $L_X = d\circ i_X + i_X\circ d$ in terms of the differential and the interior product, and make symbolic computations.

Comment: @Dldier I thought about this, too, but because the expression is $\phi L_{X} (\Delta_{g} \phi)$, even the first term which looks *tentatively* like an exact form no longer is thanks to the first $\phi$ :(

Comment: I think there will be no general reason for this expression to be vanishing on all function $\phi$ and all vector fields $X$. Why would it be?

Comment: @DLdier I have no issue with it being non-vanishing, just wondering if it is somehow a "boundary" term.